# Appcelerator: Resize Backgroundimage from window when the orientation change?

Tags: image, orientation, appcelerator

i hope you can help me.

I want that the Background image fit to the screen when the orientation changes.

At the Moment i looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/254IM.png

When i click on the Picture a new window will open with the big picture as background. As you see below that only works well when i turn the ipad left or right. At the portrait mode the picture doesn´t fit very well to the screen.

ttp://i.imgur.com/hqP8y.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGMWm.png

Here is the Code for the opening window when i click a picture:

```
     var button2 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
     backgroundImage:'./images/4sm.png',
        height:hoehe,
        width:breite,
        top:oben,
        left:links

     });
     scrollView.add(button2);

     button2.addEventListener('click', function()
     {

        var w2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
            backgroundImage:'./images/4.png'
        });
        w2.addEventListener('click', function()
        {
            w2.close();
        });

        w2.open();
     });
```

How can i change the backgroundimage properties when the ipad is in landscape or portrait mode?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this [guide](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Handling+Device+Orientation#HandlingDeviceOrientation-HandlingOrientationChanges) here on orientation change handlers.

Comment: Real answers are preferred over bare links.  To correct the problem, please summarize the content of the page you linked in your answer here.